# Connect WL 6.2.0.1 device binaries to MFP 7.1 WLAPP

Tags: migration, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We are upgrading our Platform from WL6.2.0.1 to MFP 7.1. However, I have one concerns as our applications that are built with WL 6.2.0.1 are live on the store.

Based on the following URL, it is indicating that I can run WL 6.2.0.1 (war,wlapp,adapter) on MFP7.1

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_compat.html?lang=en

However,If we upgraded our PROD environment to 7.1 and deployed (war,.wlapp and .adapters) that are complied with MFP 7.1, can still our application that is on App store which is built with WL 6.2.0.1 connect and works with no issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

The application server that you deploy MobileFirst Server on is able to serve two (or more) .war files (projects), for example that of 6.2 in order to continue and serve the existing application and that of 7.1 in order to serve new applications. The server.xml file needs to be configured accordingly in order to support this.

The idea is that once this setup is live, you can then Remote Disable the 6.2 apps and have users migrate to the 7.1-based app. Once that's done, you can probably remove the 6.2 war...

I suggest to read these entire topics: 
- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/topics/t_upgrading.html
- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/topics/c_install_config.html

Comment: Thank you Idan, so I need to deploy 6.2 war with its artifices on MFP to serve my live application along with another war file for my application that is built with 7.1 (ie, MFP will have 2 runtimes, one for 6.2 and the other for 7.1). Once my 7.1 App store is live I can remote disable 6.2 and force the users to 7.1 app. correct?